# How do I correctly declare a Dependency to another Bundle within a Bundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I am trying to use a Bundle inside a Bundle but somehow it is failig.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/myname/mybundle"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    (...)
    "myname/mybundle": "*"
},
```

this seems to work so far. But I can't figure out how to declare another dependency within "myname/mybundle".

I tried the following in the composer.json file of myname/mybundle but none of them worked :(

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "url": "https://github.com/drymek/PheanstalkBundle"
    }
],
"require": {
    (...)
    "drymek/PheanstalkBundle": "dev-master"
}
```

and

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "drymek/PheanstalkBundle",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/drymek/PheanstalkBundle.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    (...)
    "drymek/PheanstalkBundle": "dev-master"
}
```

when I rum `composer.phar update` all i get is

`- myname/mybundle dev-master requires drymek/pheanstalkbundle dev-master -> no matching package found.`

Comment: The second repository is at https://github.com/digitalpioneers/pheanstalk or at https://github.com/drymek/PheanstalkBundle ?

Comment: whoops sorry drymek/PheanstalkBundle... corrected it now ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I've found an answer [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/04-schema.md#repositories-root-only)

It states: `Repositories are not resolved recursively. You can only add them to your main composer.json. Repository declarations of dependencies' composer.jsons are ignored`.

That's too bad... but now at least I know where to put my dependeny (in the root composer.json file)

Comment: That means composer is not **that** much better than the old deps file. I wonder wheter it's a bad idea to solve it recursively, or it's just that they didn't implement this yet.

Comment: At least you're able get your bundle's composer.json file considered. Im facing a really weird issue in a similar scenario. My projects need to retrieve some custom zip packages, in these packages a composer.json file defines other requirements. The repositories of these requirements are declared in the root composer.json file.

The thing is that after the zip file is downloaded, unpacked and placed in the vendor dir, composer totally ignores its composer.json where package's requirements are defined... Any idea?

Comment: hey giuliano, sorry but I don't know the answer to that... but as I see you got an answer on your thread anyways. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023126/composer-ignoring-zip-dependecies-composer-json-file

Comment: Nowadays composer does check required dependencies in the composer.json file of bundles.

Comment: @BigJ: According to the Composer FAQ (as linked in the answer), this is not true for dependencies in VCS repositories.

Answer (score 0):

For bundle dependencies, please see my library https://github.com/AshleyDawson/MultiBundle. As an example, extend the MultiBundle and implement the getBundles() method, like so:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle;

use AshleyDawson\MultiBundle\AbstractMultiBundle;

class AcmeMyBundle extends AbstractMultiBundle
{
     /**
      * Optional: define a protected constructor to stop instantiation     outside of registerInto()
      */
     protected function __construct()
     {

     }

    /**
     * Define bundles that this bundle depends on
     */
    protected static function getBundles()
    {
        return array(
           new Acme\FooBundle\AcmeFooBundle(),
           new Acme\BarBundle\AcmeBarBundle(),
        );
    }
}
```

And then in the AppKernel register the bundle and it's dependencies:

```
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...,
        );

        // Register my bundle and its dependencies
        \Acme\MyBundle\AcmeMyBundle::registerInto($bundles);

        // ...
    }
}
```